# Getting maximum occurred word in Hadoop Mapreduce word count

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

So, I've been following the Mapreduce python code on this website (http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) which returns a word count from a text file (i.e. the word and the number of times it occurs in the text). However, I would like to know how to return the maximum occurred word. The mapper and reducer are as follows -

```
#Mapper

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()
    # increase counters
    for word in words:
        # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
        # what we output here will be the input for the
        # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
        #
        # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)

#Reducer

from operator import itemgetter
import sys

current_word = None
current_count = 0
word = None

# input comes from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()

    # parse the input we got from mapper.py
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    # convert count (currently a string) to int
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        # count was not a number, so silently
        # ignore/discard this line
        continue

    # this IF-switch only works because Hadoop sorts map output
    # by key (here: word) before it is passed to the reducer
    if current_word == word:
        current_count += count
    else:
        if current_word:
            # write result to STDOUT
            print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count)
        current_count = count
        current_word = word

# do not forget to output the last word if needed!
if current_word == word:
    print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count)
```

So, I know I need to add something to the end of the reducer, but I'm just not entirely sure what.

Comment: So you simply want to find the word that had the largest count and output it?

Comment: Exactly. The word with the largest count along with the count itself.

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a little bit of code to add at the end of the reducer, but I've tried to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set only one reducer to aggregate all values (`-numReduceTasks 1`)

this how your reduce should look like:

```
max_count = 0
max_word = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()

    # parse the input we got from mapper.py
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    # convert count (currently a string) to int
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        # count was not a number, so silently
        # ignore/discard this line
        continue

    # this IF-switch only works because Hadoop sorts map output
    # by key (here: word) before it is passed to the reducer
    if current_word == word:
        current_count += count
    else:
        # check if new word greater
        if current_count > max_count:
            max_count= current_count 
            max_word = current_word        
        current_count = count
        current_word = word

# do not forget to check last word if needed!
if current_count > max_count:
    max_count= current_count 
    max_word = current_word

print '%s\t%s' % (max_word, max_count)
```

But with only one reducer you looses parallelization, so maybe it would be faster if you run this job after the first one, not instead. In this way, your mapper will be the same as reducer.